# Django - Pathing Issue (I think!)

Tags: python, django, path, django-urls

I've created a restuarant booking system using Django. Trying to achieve full Crud functionality. Just trying to sort out the update and delete.
So basically when i open the user account it comes up with the reservations they've made and the option to edit or Delete them.

Where my issue is is when i have my url paths as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ReservationsFormView.as_view(), name='reservations'),
    path('edit/<slug:pk>/', EditReservationView.as_view(), name="edit_reservation"),
    path('view/<slug:pk>/', ReservationCompleteView.as_view(), 
name="reservation_complete"),
    path('reservations_account/', ReservationAccountView.as_view(), 
name="reservations_account"),
    path('delete/<slug:pk>/', DeleteReservationView.as_view(), 
name="delete_reservation"),
]
```

It won't load the account screen as it says:
[error screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW6Xw.png)

and when I change my paths to as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ReservationsFormView.as_view(), name='reservations'),
    path('edit_reservation', EditReservationView.as_view(), name="edit_reservation"),
    path('view_reservation/', ReservationCompleteView.as_view(), 
name="reservation_complete"),
    path('reservations_account/', ReservationAccountView.as_view(), 
name="reservations_account"),
    path('delete_reservation/', DeleteReservationView.as_view(), 
name="delete_reservation"),
]
```

It does load the account screen but when i hit the Edit or Delete button i get the following:

[error screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTnM5.png)

My views.py file:

```
class ReservationsFormView(CreateView):
    model = Reservations
    template_name = "reservations/reservations.html"
    form_class = ReservationForm
    success_url = "reservation_complete/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class EditReservationView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, 
UpdateView):
    form_class = ReservationForm
    template_name = 'reservations/edit_reservation.html'
    success_url = "/reservations_account/"
    model = Reservations

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user


class ReservationCompleteView(CreateView):
    template_name = "reservations/reservation_complete.html"
    success_url = "/reservation_complete/"
    form_class = ReservationForm
    model = Reservations


class ReservationAccountView(ListView):
    template_name = "reservations/reservations_account.html"
    model = Reservations

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'reservations': 
self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user),
        }
        return context


class DeleteReservationView(LoginRequiredMixin, 
UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    """ A view to delete an reservation """
    model = Reservations
    success_url = "/reservations_account/"

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user
```

Relatively new to Django so any help is grealy appreciated.
Thanks in adance

Comment: are you using *slugs* or primary keys?

Comment: can you show your `views.py` file?

Comment: Added my views.py file. Really appreicate the help

Comment: in `urlpatters` you have to write `<int:pk>`, instead of  `<slug:pk>`. If you want to use the slug, use a text property as lookup field.

Comment: likes this: path('edit/<int:pk>', EditReservationView.as_view(), name="edit_reservation"),

Comment: The above path did not work. Wonder have i done something wrong back in the models or something. Pretty lost

Comment: @JackCrosbie show models then, maybe something we will notice.

Comment: I actually got it, i think. I wasn't sending the slug back with the button click. Just checking now and will update accordingly